# In yii how to access other tables fields

Tags: yii

I am creating project in yii framework. I am having table as-
Qbquestion              QbquestionOption
-questionId             -optionId
-question               -questionId
-userId                 -option
-isPublished            -isAnswer

In QbquestionOption controller i want to access Qbquestion tables fields. I had written quesry as-

```
 $Question=Qbquestion::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("questionId"=>$number));
```

where $number is some random number.
When i am using its fields as= $Question->isPublished then its giving error as "trying to get access to property of non-object"
Statement var_dump($Question) is showing all record and all values of Qbquestion table. So how can i access records?
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Question` is an array of models you cannot call model function on that..

what you can do is:

```
 $questions = Qbquestion::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("questionId"=>$number));
 foreach($questions as $question)
    $question->isPublished()
```

or you can use `findByAttribute` to get single result..

Answer (score 1):

`findAllByAttributes` returns an array of objects.

If you just want one question, use `findByAttributes` instead, then it should work as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try As I don't know your relation n all. Just give a try. I'll post other answers if it don't works. Also tel me in which table isPublished field is? If it in other table as your title mentioned you need to change it as  echo $qRec->OtherTableRelationArrayKey->isPublished;

```
foreach($Question AS $qRec)
{
      echo $qRec->isPublished;
      echo "<br />";   
}
```